# Computing an integral that reduces to $\mathbb{P}[X>Y]$

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, convolution, integral

## Problem

Evaluate $$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu)}{\sigma} \right)^2}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

## My attempt

Now the first part of the integrand represents the p.d.f of the normal dist and other other the c.d.f. of the standard logistic.

So I wrote it as follows. Say $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $Y\sim \mathrm{Logistic}(0,1)$. Let $f_X,F_X$ denote the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of $X$ respectively and similarly $g_Y,G_Y$ for $Y$.

The integral to find is then given as follows,
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)G_Y(x)\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\text{Integrating by parts we get,}\\
&=\underbrace{\left. F_X(x)G_Y(x)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}}_{=1}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_Y(x)F_X(x)\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\text{but since we know} \int_{-\infty}^\infty g_Y(x) \mathrm{d}x=1 \text{, we can simplify.}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_Y(x)(1-F_X(x))\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_Y(x) \mathbb{P}(X>x)\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&\text{With the law of total probability we get}\\
&=P(X>Y).
\end{align*}

Here I'm stuck. Not sure how to simplify it. I read about the convolution of probability distributions and it seems like the initial integral is like the c.d.f. of $X+Y$.

But I don't see how to proceed with that direction either.

Comment: You can approximate this or compute it using numerical methods.  I am unaware of any reduction to a simpler expression (having looked for one in the past).

Comment: Oh well, thanks for letting me know.